# Let $A→B$ be injective morphism of $R-$module and $B$ is flat as $R-$module. How can I prove $A \otimes_R C→B \otimes_R C$ is injective?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, modules

Let $R$ be commutative ring.Let $A→B$ be injective morphism of $R-$module and $B$ is flat as $R-$module.
How can I prove $A \otimes_R C→B \otimes_R C$ is injective ?

I'm having trouble where to use the condition '$B$ is flat'.
If this is a famous fact, I appreciated if you could tell me reference( book, pdf, and so on).

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Why would you need flatness here? Injectivity OTOH (in the case where $A\to B$ were injective).

Comment: Sorry for my typo, I edited.

Comment: Are you sure the condition is not “$C$ is flat”?

Answer (score 1):

That is not true. Consider $B = R = k[x]$, $A = (x) \subset k[x]$ and $C = k[x] / (x)$. So there is a short exact sequence
$$\tag{1} 0 \to A \to B \to C \to 0.$$
By construction, the morphism $C = B \otimes_R C \to C \otimes_R C = C$ is an isomorphism, which means (by right exactness of $-\otimes_R C$) that
$$A \otimes_R C \to B \otimes_R C$$
is the zero map. On the other hand, $A$ is free as an $R$-module, so $A \otimes_R C \neq 0$.

Comment: If $C$ is flat, what will happen ? Tensoring $C$ over $R$ is then exact functor ?

Comment: @afortiori Yes, that is the definition "$C$ is flat".